# How extract xml value from xmldata column in table using Oracle Query

Tags: xml, oracle

I have table xx_xml_data_table

### ID    XMLDATA   creation_date  XML_REQUEST_ID

1         10-JAN-2022       11386
2         10-JAN-2022       11386

I have xmladata like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<COLLECTIONSET><PARTY_ID>123</PARTY_ID><ACCOUNT_ID>456</ACCOUNT_ID><LOCATION_ID>789</LOCATION_ID><CONTACT_ID>090</CONTACT_ID>
 <COLLECTION>
  <CURRSYSDATE>11/15/2022</CURRSYSDATE>
  <FIRST_NAME>FNAME</FIRST_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>LNAMEt</LAST_NAME>
  <PAYMENT_HISTORY>
   <PAYMENT_HISTORY_ROW>
    <INVOICE_NUMBER>inv0001</INVOICE_NUMBER>
    <PAY_STATUS>OPEN</PAY_STATUS>
    <AMOUNT_DUE_ORIGINAL>123</AMOUNT_DUE_ORIGINAL>
    <AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>100</AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>
    <INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE>INR</INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE>
    <ACCTD_AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>100</ACCTD_AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>
    <FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY>INR</FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY>
    <DUE_DAYS>17</DUE_DAYS>
    <DUE_DATE>29-OCT-2022</DUE_DATE>
   </PAYMENT_HISTORY_ROW>
   <PAYMENT_HISTORY_ROW>
    <INVOICE_NUMBER>inv0002</INVOICE_NUMBER>
    <PAY_STATUS>OPEN</PAY_STATUS>
    <AMOUNT_DUE_ORIGINAL>555</AMOUNT_DUE_ORIGINAL>
    <AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>200</AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>
    <INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE>INR</INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE>
    <ACCTD_AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>200</ACCTD_AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING>
    <FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY>INR</FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY>
    <DUE_DAYS>17</DUE_DAYS>
    <DUE_DATE>29-OCT-2022</DUE_DATE>
   </PAYMENT_HISTORY_ROW>
  </PAYMENT_HISTORY>
 </COLLECTION>
</COLLECTIONSET>
```

I tried this query but not working:

```
WITH inv AS
     (SELECT xt2.INVOICE_NUMBER,
             t.ID
           FROM xx_xml_data_table t,
        XMLTABLE('/COLLECTIONSET/COLLECTION/PAYMENT_HISTORY/PAYMENT_HISTORY_ROW' PASSING t.XMLDATA
                 COLUMNS "INVOICE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(40)  PATH '@INVOICE_NUMBER' ) xt2
        where  t.XML_REQUEST_ID IN (11386,11387))
SELECT * FROM inv;
```

I need result like:

ID Invoice_number
1  inv0001
1  inv0002
2  inv4001
2  inv4002

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: Yes, its not working

Comment: what is "not working"  No data comes back? an error??

Comment: error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 20

Comment: What data type is your `XMLDATA` column?

Comment: its CLOB datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example XML, `INVOICE_NUMBER` is a node, not an attribute, so your path should be `'INVOICE_NUMBER'` rather than `'@INVOICE_NUMBER'`.

You can also simplify a bit - you don't seem to need the CTE:

```
SELECT xt2.INVOICE_NUMBER,
       t.ID
  FROM xx_xml_data_table t,
       XMLTABLE(
         '/COLLECTIONSET/COLLECTION/PAYMENT_HISTORY/PAYMENT_HISTORY_ROW'
         PASSING t.XMLDATA
         COLUMNS "INVOICE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(40) PATH 'INVOICE_NUMBER'
       ) xt2
WHERE t.XML_REQUEST_ID IN (11386,11387);
```

| INVOICE_NUMBER | ID |
| --- | --- |
| inv0001 | 1 |
| inv0002 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JpPTHJIt)

If your `XMLDATA` column is defined as a string (`varchar2` or `clob`) then you will ned to convert that to XMLType in the `PASSING` clause; otherwise you'll get an error, which could be ORA-00932 or ORA-19224 or something else, depending on the actual data type; so you would do:

```
SELECT xt2.INVOICE_NUMBER,
       t.ID
  FROM xx_xml_data_table t,
       XMLTABLE(
         '/COLLECTIONSET/COLLECTION/PAYMENT_HISTORY/PAYMENT_HISTORY_ROW'
         PASSING XMLType(t.XMLDATA)
         COLUMNS "INVOICE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(40) PATH 'INVOICE_NUMBER'
       ) xt2
WHERE t.XML_REQUEST_ID IN (11386,11387);
```

| INVOICE_NUMBER | ID |
| --- | --- |
| inv0001 | 1 |
| inv0002 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c5t40AnW)

Comment: I am getting this error

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 18

Comment: @Karun - which which query? If `XMLDATA` is a CLOB then the second query with `XMLType(t.XMLDATA)` should work...

Comment: after using "XMLType" it's working now. Thank You So Much!!!!